# GIDSignIn sharedInstance configuration crashing the app

Tags: ios, xcode8, google-signin

I have a small iOS app (xcode8 ios10) where I need the user to login with facebook or with google. I have done the facebook part and its working great. Then today I added the google signin support. I manually downloaded and installed the SDK.

All is well and builds well. But when the code executes

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
```

the app crashes giving the error:

> [__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x618000262e00'

I tried looking for the occurence of *gtm_httpArgumentsString* in my code and its no where to be found.

Can anyone help? I followed the google instructions step by step and this makes no sense to me now.

Comment: can you add a google.plist file in project?

Comment: Please check and tell me

Comment: check that com.google."somethingid" is same in plist of URL scheme and google.plist

Comment: Google plist is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Google Utilities framework  which are available in google_signin_sdk folder :

Comment: I added this, now its throwing some x86_64 architecture not found lol

Comment: got it, after adding back the GoogleUtilities.framework I needed to add libz.dylib in the linked libraries. All good now. Thanks